# What is the 'Visual Studio Debugger ETW Service'?

Tags: visual-studio

I have this Windows Service on my development machine that's eating large amount of my memory when I run the application we're developing.

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 1.
Windows 8.1
.NET 4.5.51641

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager]

Comment: Marked @Robert Harvey's answer because I deduced Visual Studio uses it for high-speed debugging. I was running a testing application, using Visual Studio, that sends random TCP packets to our application, at a high-rate. When I ran the test application outside Visual Studio, the VS ETW Service stopped running ramping up the memory.

Comment: From his link: 'Event Tracing for Windows® (ETW) is a general-purpose, high-speed tracing facility provided by the operating system. Using a buffering and logging mechanism implemented in the kernel, ETW provides a tracing mechanism for events raised by both user-mode applications and kernel-mode device drivers.'

Comment: I had the same symptom but for an other reason: I was constantly creating Tasks inside of my Tasks in a recursive way... Something like this: public Task NotifyAsync() { return Task.Run(()=> NotifyAsync()); }  I had just forgotten to remove the Async at the end of the inner method call... silly me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event Tracing for Windows.   See the article [Improve Debugging And Performance Tuning With ETW in April 2007 Edition of the MSDN Magazine](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineApril2007en-us.chm) for more details.

Comment: This link is dead. It appears to be from MSDN April 2007 and their website only goes back to 2009 for content. A different article: [Event Tracing For Windows – what it is and useful tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/08/05/etw-event-tracing-for-windows-what-it-is-and-useful-tools.aspx)

Comment: Nope, also dead :-(